# How set text/image of specific one ListView row - Android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

Thanks to help from stackoverflow users I have managed to change colour of one specific row based on some condition. But changing colour doesn't fully fit my needs and expectations.

So I started looking through web and trying to change it. I want to set text in TextView of specific row. To be able to change row colour I was advised to create personalised SimpleCursorAdapter class as I am getting values into ListView from SQLite using Cursor.

After reading and testing it this is what I came up with:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        if(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBAdapter.KEY_PRICE)) == 5)
        {   
            TextView price = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.priceInfo);
            price.setText("High");
        }
        else
            view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    }
}
```

However, what I am getting now is duplicated text on some rows (there is regularity in it). As I read somewhere, every scroll is refreshing ListView, but how it is possible that when I put in if clause (insted of this TextView) this line: `view.setBackgroundColor(SELECTED_COLOR);` everything works fine and only this one row had been changed.

Can someone please tell me what I have to do to make it works, or what is wrong in my thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);         
        TextView price = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.priceInfo);
        if(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBAdapter.KEY_PRICE)) == 5)
        {   
            price.setText("High");
            view.setBackgroundColor(/* red color? */);
        }
        else {
            price.setText("");
            view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        }
    }
}
```

Because of "itemrecycling" the view in the bindView has colors and text that is been recycled. You need to assign all properties explicitly for each bindView call that change over different listview items. in this case the backgroundcolor and price label.

Answer (score 0):

override getView method and use convertView.setbackgroundColor based on the position of the listview item.

Something like this:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
String[] objects) {
super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
if(postion == 1) //1st position in listview
 {
   convertView.setbackgroundColor(...)
 }
```

and so on...

Comment: 1. I do not want to change background colour. I can do it now, much easier. 2. So if I have got 2 000 elements I have to make a loop or something and work on such crazy things?

Comment: As far as I have known listview (it is a little messy, yes), if u want to modify elements in some rows, the best way to go about in doing it is by comparing the positions within the list.

Comment: So, you don't know good. The method that I post in my question is working when we are talking about row colour change. But it isn't working with text or image set. And you don't have to make any loop if you have got cursor.